# wamp ssi not working

Tags: html, wamp, ssi

i am working with wamp. i want to use ssi so i have changed following lines in httpd.conf but it does not seem to be working :

```
AddType text/html .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
Options +Includes
```

**test.html**

```
<html>
<title>This is incl html</title>
<!--#include file="menu.shtml" -->
</html>
```

**menu.shtml**

```
<h1>hheelloo</h1>
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 7):

Add to your projects root directory a .htaccess files with the following.

```
AddType text/html .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .html
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
DirectoryIndex index.shtml index.html
```

This should allow includes to work on that project.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this same problem until I found this link -

http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/php/phpbasics/Setting-Up-SSI-On-Wamp.html

The gist of the answer is below. It seems the lines need to be added in a specific location within the file. They also suggested a find & replace on the FollowSymLinks option -

```
How to add SSI (Serverside include support in WAMP)?
Open http.conf file from <your drive):\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\conf (e.g. C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\conf)
Then add the following code:
AddType text/html .shtml
Options +Includes
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
**The above code should be above "<Directory />" in httpd.conf file**
Then find "Options Indexes FollowSymLinks" and replace it with:
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Includes
Restart wamp and enjoy.
```

Following these steps worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work instead of < !--#include file:

```
<!--#include virtual="menu.shtml" -->
```

I also have this under my AddType text/html .shtml line:

```
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

fyi I'm not an expert, I just looked at how my own server is set up. I hope it helps